# Saving a sequence of numbers to an array

Tags: java, arrays

There is a code for solving the Lorentz system, I need to save all the solutions x, y, z at each iteration in the corresponding array solutions, that is, 5000 solutions x, y, z put in an array, how is this best done? How to translate arrays to a string then?

```
public class Butterfly {

public static double dx(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -10*(x - y);
}

public static double dy(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -x*z + 28*x - y;
}

public static double dz(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*y - 8*z/3;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 0.0, y = 20.0, z = 25.0; //
    double dt = 0.001;



    // uses Euler method
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {


        // 
        double xnew = x + dx(x, y, z) * dt;
        double ynew = y + dy(x, y, z) * dt;
        double znew = z + dz(x, y, z) * dt;
        x = xnew; 
        y = ynew;
        z = znew;
        double[][] xyzArray = new double[5000][3];
        for (i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < xyzArray.length; j++) {
                xyzArray[i][j] = x;

            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < xyzArray.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(xyzArray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
       }
   }
}
```

Аfter editing the code the program displays 5000 times one value x, y, z, not all the values. I think that in this way lost the other solutions. After all, I have 5000 decisions of each variable, I need to save each...

```
 // uses Euler method
       double[][] xyzArray = new double[5000][3];
       for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
            for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {

            double xnew = x + dx(x, y, z) * dt;
            double ynew = y + dy(x, y, z) * dt;
            double znew = z + dz(x, y, z) * dt;

            xyzArray[i][0] = xnew;
            xyzArray[i][1] = ynew;
            xyzArray[i][2] = znew;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(xyzArray[i][0] + ", " + xyzArray[i][1] + ", " + xyzArray[i][2]);

    }

}
```

after editing the following code is produced. 5,000 solutions of the first iteration are still output: it does not work in IDEAS or in jshell. I understand that the code is correct, but I can not understand why I get the wrong result

```
public class Butterfly {

public static double dx(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -10 * (x - y);
}

public static double dy(double x, double y, double z) {
    return -x * z + 28 * x - y;
}

public static double dz(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x * y - 8 * z / 3;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   double x = 0.0, y = 20.0, z = 25.0;
   double dt = 0.001;
   double[][] xyzArray = new double[5000][3];
   for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
        double xnew = x + dx(x, y, z) * dt;
        double ynew = y + dy(x, y, z) * dt;
        double znew = z + dz(x, y, z) * dt;
        xyzArray[i][0] = xnew;
        xyzArray[i][1] = ynew;
        xyzArray[i][2] = znew;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(xyzArray[i][0] + ", " + xyzArray[i][1] + ", " + xyzArray[i][2]);


    }

 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you want 3 arrays or 1 two-dimensional array?   What do you mean by translating arrays to strings, as the array of just the x values, separate from the array of y and z values isn’t useful; you’d want x,y,z grouped together.

Comment: I need one two-dimensional array of all values, then I want to mix all solutions from this array with the string using the xor @AJNeufeld

Comment: Do you know how to declare a two-dimensional array?  Do you know how to create it, after you’ve declared it?  Do you know how to store & retrieve values in an array?  If so, it shouldn’t be a stretch to use `[i]` as one of the indices.  **Edit** your post to include what you’ve tried.  It doesn’t matter that it doesn’t work, or doesn’t even compile.  This is not a code-writing service, but we will try to help you, if you’ve demonstrated that you’ve actually tried to solve the problem.

Comment: As for “_mix all solutions from this array with the string using xor_” ... WHAT?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to declare and create a two-dimensional array array. how to store and retrieve the values I do not know. I do not understand how you can put all the values of a solution x in an array. I tried so, but this is the wrong decision –I edited the code in a post @AJNeufeld

Comment: “mix all solutions from this array with the string using xor” ---- I wanted to use this set of solutions to mix with the message to get the encrypted message...

Comment: You'll need to _ask a new question_ for how to mix the solutions to get an encrypted message.  It is a _completely different_ question from "Saving a sequence of numbers to an array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your array inside the loop.  You don't want to create 5000 copies of your array of 5000 data points!  You want only 1 array of 5000 data points, so you need to declare and create the array outside the loop.

```
double[][] xyzArray = new double[5000][3];

// uses Euler method
for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {

    // ... compute xnew, ynew, znew ... etc ...
```

Once you've got your new values for the current step, you want to save them in the `[i]`-th entry of your array.  You'll store `x` in the `[i][0]` sub-entry, `y` in the `[i][1]` sub-entry, and `z` in the `[i][2]` sub-entry.

```
    xyzArray[i][0] = xnew;
    xyzArray[i][1] = ynew;
    xyzArray[i][2] = znew;
```

To print the values out after all values have been computed:

```
} // end of Euler method loop

for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(xyzArray[i][0] + ", " + xyzArray[i][1] +", " + xyzArray[i][2]);
}
```

---

Your [revision 3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50630353/3) works.

- View your revision 3 code
- Copy the program text
- Paste it in a `jshell`
- Execute it with `Butterfly.main(new String[] {})`

And you will see your 5000 x,y,z values -- all different.

```
C:\>"\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\jshell.exe"
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 10
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> public class Butterfly {
   ...>
   ...> public static double dx(double x, double y, double z) {
   ...>     return -10*(x - y);

         [... many lines omitted for brevity ...]

   ...>     }
   ...>    }
   ...> }
|  created class Butterfly

jshell> Butterfly.main(new String[] {})
0.2, 19.98, 24.933333333333334
0.39780000000000004, 19.960633333333334, 24.870840444444443
0.5934283333333333, 19.9419174796712, 24.81245854319926
0.786913224796712, 19.92386713960567, 24.758126085937494

         [... many lines omitted for brevity ...]

0.381817425662861, 0.5879585365342771, 12.654916756967012
0.38387883677157514, 0.59322959817818, 12.621394805096582
0.3859723443856412, 0.5985398896533907, 12.587965480571079
0.3880980198383187, 0.6038899688589537, 12.554628592467306

jshell>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I fixed the code in the post and the program displays 5000 times one value x, y, z, not all the values. I think that in this way lost the other solutions. After all, I have 5000 decisions of each variable, I need to save each @AJNeufeld

Comment: You can edit your post to add details and/or clarify the problem.  Completely changing the question is not allowed, as it invalidates any comments or answers posted by others.  For example, my answer contains, "You've declared your array inside your loop", but your [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50630353/3) edit changes the code so that my answer no longer makes sense.  As such, I've rollbacked back your edit.

Comment: Incidentally, your [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50630353/3) code works just fine when I run it, and prints 5000 different x,y,z values.  So your local copy doesn't match what you attempted to post.  Compare the two to find your error.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I can not edit the post this way. I get 5000 times 3 identical values of 0.2, 19.98, 24.933333333333334 @AJNeufeld

Comment: If you look at your recent edit, you'll see a double loop: `for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.length; i++) { for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {`.  You don't want a double loop ... that would be solving the system 5000*5000 times ... except you're using the same loop index `i`, so the outer loop will only execute once using `i = 0`, and the inner loop will increment until `i == 5000`, and the outer loop is at the termination condition.  Your revision 3 code works.  Compare it with your local copy.

Comment: As for 5000 copies of `0.2, 19.98, 24.93333`, that is the output of the first iteration.  You are no longer copying `x = xnew; y = ynew; z = znew;` so your subsequent iterations are still using your initial condition values, not the newly computed values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not use the double loop and use the version 3 code, but I get only three solutions x, y, z: 0.2, 19.98, 24.933333333333334. If I do not use a two-dimensional array, and right after x = xnew I bring solutions to the screen, then I get all the solutions without exception... but how to use the newly computed values ?@AJNeufeld

Comment: Your version 3 code includes `x = xnew;  y = ynew; z = znew;` inside the computation loop, and properly fills in the two-dimesional array.  If you found this answer helpful, please upvote it (up-arrow on the left near top of the answer).  If this answers the question "_Saving a sequence of numbers to an array_" please accept the answer (check-mark to the left of the answer).  If you have questions about using the data generated from your Lorentz system to encrypt a message, please **ask a new question** specifically about that.

Comment: I do not want to print only the first iteration, I need to output a copy of all the iterations

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you a transcript, demonstrating what I have been saying.  Your revision 3 code **is** a complete, working, correct version of the code to generate the 2d array, with unique solution values.  You took my initial answer, attempted to paste it into your local code, got it wrong, edited your question to post what you did, but actually got it right in the that post.  Your subsequent edit posted your local changes, which added in a double loop and deleted the `x = xnew; y = ynew; z = znew;` lines.  Just look at the revision 3 code; it is correct.

Comment: I edited the code in a post, still 5000 decisions of the first iteration are output: it does not work in IDEA or in jshell. I understand that the code is correct, but I can not understand why I get the wrong result @AJNeufeld

Comment: thank you very much for your help, unnecessary questions were due to neglect @AJNeufeld